# Loosing information after the segmentation of the MR image using ITKsnap

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, nifti

I am working with DICOM images, which i have converted to NIFTI. I have 100 dicom images of one patient and i am using dcm2niix to do the conversion. It is giving me 4d info which i expect, i.e., 240, 196, 1, 100. Later, i have used that NIFTI file to to perform segmentation using ITKSnap but seems like i am loosing some information after segmentation (like desc, aux_file info, etc.). Can anyone please help? I have added header of my 1st NIFTI file and Segmented NIFTI file below.

```
`1st NIFTI File`

sizeof_hdr      : 348

data_type       : b''

db_name         : b''

extents         : 0

session_error   : 0

regular         : b'r'

dim_info        : 57

dim             : \[  4 240 196   1 100   1   1   1\]

intent_p1       : 0.0

intent_p2       : 0.0

intent_p3       : 0.0

intent_code     : none

datatype        : int16

bitpix          : 16

slice_start     : 0

pixdim          : \[-1.         1.5833334  1.5833334  6.         0.028      0.
0\.         0.       \]

vox_offset      : 0.0

scl_slope       : nan

scl_inter       : nan

slice_end       : 0

slice_code      : unknown

xyzt_units      : 10

cal_max         : 0.0

cal_min         : 0.0

slice_duration  : 0.0

toffset         : 0.0

glmax           : 0

glmin           : 0

descrip         : b'TE=1.2;Time=103829.298;phase=1'

aux_file        : b'RR 872 +/- 61; 9 heartb'

qform_code      : scanner

sform_code      : scanner

quatern_b       : 0.0

quatern_c       : 1.0

quatern_d       : 0.0

qoffset_x       : 191.80186

qoffset_y       : -134.34802

qoffset_z       : 43.5763

srow_x          : \[ -1.5833334   0.         -0.        191.80186  \]

srow_y          : \[  -0.           1.5833334   -0.        -134.34802  \]

srow_z          : \[ 0.      0.      6.     43.5763\]

intent_name     : b''

magic           : b'n+1'


`Segmented NIFTI file`

sizeof_hdr      : 348

data_type       : b''

db_name         : b''

extents         : 0

session_error   : 0

regular         : b'r'

dim_info        : 0

dim             : \[  4 240 196   1 100   1   1   1\]

intent_p1       : 0.0

intent_p2       : 0.0

intent_p3       : 0.0

intent_code     : none

datatype        : uint16

bitpix          : 16

slice_start     : 0

pixdim          : \[-1.         1.5833334  1.5833334  6.         0.028      0.
0\.         0.       \]

vox_offset      : 0.0

scl_slope       : nan

scl_inter       : nan

slice_end       : 0

slice_code      : unknown

xyzt_units      : 2

cal_max         : 0.0

cal_min         : 0.0

slice_duration  : 0.0

toffset         : 0.0

glmax           : 0

glmin           : 0

descrip         : b''

aux_file        : b''

qform_code      : scanner

sform_code      : scanner

quatern_b       : -0.0

quatern_c       : 1.0

quatern_d       : 0.0

qoffset_x       : 191.80186

qoffset_y       : -134.34802

qoffset_z       : 43.5763

srow_x          : \[ -1.5833334  -0.          0.        191.80186  \]

srow_y          : \[  -0.           1.5833334   -0.        -134.34802  \]

srow_z          : \[ 0.      0.      6.     43.5763\]

intent_name     : b''

magic           : b'n+1'

`end`
```

How can i retain the information in segmented NIFTI file?

I have tried using ITKSnap, 3d slicer. Using 3d slicer, i am loosing a lot of information, that's why i am sticking to ITKSnap for manual segmentation.

I am expecting the time stamp information to be there in segmented file.

Comment: Unless the segmentation is changing this info for some reason, I expect it to be the same, regarthless if MR image or segmantation. You could always just replace whatever ITK-snap gives with the original one.